Reference request for algebro geometric quotients
I am trying to get some reference for understanding different kinds of quotients arising in algebraic geometry through examples. Can anyone provide some good references.

When I was learning this subject, I learned a lot from Peter Newstead's Tata Institute Lectures on "Introduction to Moduli Problems and Orbit Spaces." There will be many more modern treatments around, but I would still recommend this as a starting point.

This seems like a reasonable question, so I don't agree with the downvotes. You can  find further references on the wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_invariant_theory
